# updating a records using external Id in Apex

Tags: apex, upsert, database, externalid

I copied the product data to another object named foo. I used only the name and externalId of product to copy it to Foo object. Foo's external id matches with product's external Id.

Some of my product's Name have changed. So I want to run a script to update corresponding foo records name. Since the external Id is same between product and foo , I can use that as a reference to upsert the records in Foo. Below is my code, however I get this error:

```
System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found: Externald__c duplicates value on record with id: a1H370000016QkV: []
```

Apex code:

```
List<Product2> products = [SELECT Name,PrdExternalId,Product__r.PrdExternalId FROM Product2 WHERE Warehouse_SKU__c!=Null];
        system.debug('Product list ********* ' + products);
            List<Foo__c> flist = new List<foo__c>();
            for(Product2 p : products){
                foo__c f = new foo__C();
                f.Externald__c = p.PrdExternalId;
                f.Name = p.Name;
                f.foo__r.Externald__c = p.Product__r.PrdExternalId; ->> NULL POINTER EXCEPTION HERE
                flist.add(f);
                }
            upsert flist;
```

Part 2- When I try to use `f.foo__r.Externald__c = p.Product__r.PrdExternalId;` to reference the self lookup on foo__c object i get

```
System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
```

Comment: You cannot do 'f.foo__r.Externald__c = p.Product__r.PrdExternalId;' updated answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use the external id in the update call

```
upsert flist Externald__c;
```

For part two of your question, seeing that you want to relate the parent and child foo records you can t do it the way you were trying but I also think that you need to create the parent separately, however I think you either need to  build a map to successfully relate the parent back to the child or have a process builder/flow do the parent mapping for you to relate the parent to the child accurately something like this:

```
List<Product2> products = [SELECT Name,PrdExternalId,Product__r.PrdExternalId FROM Product2 WHERE Warehouse_SKU__c!=Null];
    system.debug('Product list ********* ' + products);
        List<Foo__c> flist = new List<foo__c>();
        Map<String, Foo__c> parentfMap = new Map<String, foo__c>();
        for(Product2 p : products){
            foo__c f = new foo__C();
            f.Externald__c = p.PrdExternalId;
            f.Name = p.Name;
            if(!parentfMap.containsKey(p.PrdExternalId)){
                parentfMap.put(p.PrdExternalId, new Foo__c(Externald__c = p.Product__r.PrdExternalId))
            }
            
            flist.add(f);
            }
        upsert parentfMap.values() Externald__c; 
        for(Foo__c f : flist){
           f.foo__c = parentfMap.get(f.Externald__c).Id;
        }
        upsert flist Externald__c;
```

In theory that should work or be close to what you want to do

Comment: that worked.... I am trying to use the self lookup relationship on foo object  also( Update my code). I hit a null pointer exception when I try to update with the parent's external Id.

Comment: thanks... I get this error when trying the approach - `System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, Duplicate external id specified: genwatt diesel 200kw: [Externald__c]` . It seems like it is trying to insert an existing record?

Comment: Was that from the first update call or the second also is it possible that there are multiple child records for the parent product? Also is there a name for the Parent record that's created?

Comment: It's from the first upsert call.. Yes , the product records are looped in this order - paretn1 , parent 2, child 1(parent1),child2(parent1). So the Map's value gets duplicate parent1, I can make it as a set to remove the duplicates and then covert to a list to upsert..but if the parent record already exist in foo__c , would the above approach work? I am covering a scenario where the child1 may be reparented to parent2..

Comment: It should work, you just need to do a check on the key of the map to ensure it doesn't exist, made the change in the code

Comment: Is there a chance that you can let me know how this can work when a new Product is created and I want to copy that to Foo. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/220105/a-batch-job-to-copy-new-updated-records-from-one-object-to-another

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the field which you want to use an external id.

So your syntax will be

```
upsert flist Externald__c;
```

You can even use Database methods

```
Database.upsert(flist , foo__c.Externald__c, true);
```

That being said, You cannot do

```
f.foo__r.Externald__c = p.Product__r.PrdExternalId;
```

As foo__r does not exist, foo__r would only exist when you query it.(Few exceptions lies). You have recrate a new Foo__C for parent to do your dml.

```
for(Product2 p : products){
    foo__c f = new foo__C();
    f.Externald__c = p.PrdExternalId;
    f.Name = p.Name;
    Foo__c parentFoo=new Foo__c();
    parentFoo.Externald__c = p.Product__r.PrdExternalId; 

    flist.add(f);
    flist.add(parentFoo);

}


 upsert flist Externald__c;
```