# Moving data from one object to another using Apex

Tags: apex, trigger, lightning-web-components

newbie here,

I am trying to create an LWC for moving data existing in a custom (Dump) object to the standard Contact object. This LWC will have a button, which when clicked will upsert the data present in the dump object to the contact object, matching the external IDs. However, I am struggling with creating the controller class and the Javascript for the LWC. I have the basic pseudocode for it. I would appreciate it if someone could help me with the codes. TIA

Here is the pseudocode/ proposed method:

- get data from contacts in the controller class and store it in a list
- get data from the dump object in the controller class and store it in a list
- create two lists named 'contacts to insert' and 'contacts to update'
- loop over the dump objects records
- in the loop, check if the external ID exists in the list of contacts created earlier, if it does, add the dump object record to the 'contacts to update' list
- else add it to the 'contacts to insert' list
- insert the 'contacts to insert' list
- update the 'contacts to update' list

End

BTW I have created the HTML script for the LWC component (button).

Please let me know if this approach can be improved and/or the code for the LWC controller class.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a single List to Upsert the records by matching the External Id.

Please refer [updating a records using external Id in Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/220184/updating-a-records-using-external-id-in-apex)

In LWC Javascript, call the Apex method imperatively on HTML button click to perform the steps